# Sharp SH7218U doesn't boot after formatting system partition

Tags: 2.2-froyo, boot

I formatted `/system` on my Sharp SH7218U. Now it won't turn on/boot up.
The screen doesn't turn on at all, even after removing battery or plugging into PC.

PC says "unrecognized device plugged in". Apart from that, phone does not respond.
Cannot boot into recovery mode.
adb does not recognize despite it being on debugging
~~
How do i fix this? I cant find a stock ROM online for this sharp model so i cant flash it using ODIN.... unless some kind soul has a copy of a 
SH7218U stock rom

Comment: So, what is the question? If you need help, ask for it. BTW, try ODIN to reflash stock firmware.

Answer (score 1):

The system partition contains your operating system, that is, Android. If you formatted /system without flashing a new ROM, your phone cannot load any operating system because there isn't any.

You need to flash a compatible ROM for your device to make your phone usable again.

Comment: but my phone wont turn on/cannot load into clockwork recovery, so how can i flash a ROM...

Comment: Did you format only /system? Did you try booting into recovery through physical key combination (on Samsung = Power + Home +Vol up).

Comment: i formatted dalvik cache, then did a factory reset afterwards. I tried booting into recovery using the specific key combi for my Sharp (3+6+POWER) but did not work. There is no response from phone. I tried turning it on, removing battery, etc and phone does not respond. No bootscreen, LCD screen doesnt even turn on.